# OpenGL convert/translate/normalize coordinates?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am looking for some examples of (non-deprecated code) OpenGL that actually show code/conversion, step-by-step, between coordinates from start to finish, in a 2D way that use non-standard coordinates. i.e.

```
GLfloat Square[] = 
{
    -5.5f, -5.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    -5.5f,  5.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    5.5f,  5.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    5.5f, -5.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
};
```

And then using coordinates such as the above, taking these & convert them into necessary coordinates so they map to -1,1 etc & output to screen.

Every single example, tutorial I have found on the net etc, only do so using coordinates in the above range between -1<>1.

Environment: C++.

Comment: Be nice if those that downvoted actually explained why. Myself/others may learn that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you use glm (http://glm.g-truc.net/index.html) you can just use glm::ortho to create a view matrix in the same way you would use glOrtho in old-style OpenGL.

EG:

```
glm::mat4 viewMatrix = glm::ortho(-5.0f, 5.0f, -5.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

If you then plug that into your shader you should get a mapping from -5 to +5 instead of -1 to +1, or whatever scale it is that you want.

Answer (score 1):

when you use 'no' transformations in your project then you simply need to use coordinates that are placed in "**normalized device space**". That is actually a box ranging from -1 to 1 at each axis.

in that case in the vertex shader there will be line similar to this:

```
gl_Position = attribVertexPos; // no transformation
```

For 2D, if you want to provide coords from different range, all you need to do is simply scale position:

- for range -10 to 10 use vertex shader with code `gl_Position = attribVertexPos * 0.1`
- or you can look for a scaling matrix and use it as well

Comment: Does this actually change the vector itself, or simply present it with an offset?

Comment: this is code from vertex shader: you have to apply some scaling in order to be able to pass vertices in larger space that -1 to 1. But maybe use this glm::ortho, from the answer above

Comment: Thank you for reply. Is there any way to do this with modern Opengl without using shaders?

Comment: with modern opengl you have to use some shaders... at least vertex and fragment. Other option is to use some third party library that will do this for you.